# Conditionally changing field properties in Python Marshmallow

Tags: python, marshmallow

I'm trying to implement some logic in a class that extends marshmallow.Schema such that I can override the default value for the load_only property of one of the fields in a method decorated with pre_dump.

By default, load_only=True but I would like to be able to set this to False in certain circumstances and thought the best way to achieve this would be to set a context value that can be checked in the pre dump method and then set load_only=False to include the field during serialization.

To demonstrate this, I have a ParentSchema class and a ChildSchema class. ParentSchema has a field called children that contains an list of ChildSchema objects.

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, post_load, pre_dump
import json


class Child(object):
    def __init__(self, id=None, data=None, parent_id=None):
        self.id = id
        self.data = data
        self.parent_id = parent_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'id=' + str(self.id) + ', data=' + str(self.data) + ', parent_id=' + str(self.parent_id)


class ChildSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    data = fields.String(required=True)
    parent_id = fields.Integer(required=False)

    @post_load
    def make_child(self, data, **kwargs):
        return Child(**data)


class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, id=None, data=None, children=None):
        self.id = id
        self.data = data
        self.children = children

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'id=' + str(self.id) + ', data=' + str(self.data) + ', children=' + str(self.children)


class ParentSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    data = fields.String(required=True)
    children = fields.Nested(ChildSchema, many=True, load_only=True)

    @post_load
    def make_parent(self, data, **kwargs):
        return Parent(**data)

    @pre_dump
    def check_context(self, data, **kwargs):
        if 'dump_children' in self.context:
            self.fields['children'].load_only = False
        return data
```

The default behaviour should be to not serialize the children field but if the key 'dump_children' is provided in the context dict when creating the ParentSchema object, load_only is set to False, which I would expect would result in the children field be serialized.

```
parent_data = [
    {
        "data": "parent 1",
        "children": [
            {
                "data": "child 1"
            },
            {
                "data": "child 2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "data": "parent 2",
        "children": [
            {
                "data": "child 3"
            }
        ]
    }
]

parents = ParentSchema(context={'dump_children': True}, many=True).dump(parent_data)
print(json.dumps(parents, indent=2))
```

What I don't understand is why, despite load_only being set to False as expected, this produces:

```
[
  {
    "data": "parent 1"
  },
  {
    "data": "parent 2"
  }
]
```

instead of:

```
[
  {
    "data": "parent 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "data": "child 1"
      },
      {
        "data": "child 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "data": "parent 2",
    "children": [
      {
        "data": "child 3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there some other logic that is preventing this field from being serialized? Or is there a better way to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I wanted to do something similar using `context` to control what gets dumped and I came across your question. A little digging in the [`source code`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/marshmallow/schema.html#Schema.dump) shows that the process of dumping does not dynamically determine the fields to be output using those with `load_only=False`. In fact changing that attribute on fields after the initialisation of your Schema instance seems to have no effect at all. Instead it determines which fields to dump using the `dump_fields` attribute which is set on initialisation by the `_init_fields()` method. In theory you might be able to just call that method again after changing the `load_only` attribute of `children` but it's a private api method and that seems pretty hacky.

If you are wanting to control what is output conditionally I think you are better off using `only`/`exclude`:

```
parents_only = ParentSchema(exclude=('children',), many=True)
parents_only.dump(parent_data)

[{'data': 'parent 1'}, {'data': 'parent 2'}]

parents_and_children = ParentSchema(many=True)
parents_and_children.dump(parent_data)

[{'data': 'parent 1', 'children': [{'data': 'child 1'}, {'data': 'child 2'}]}, {'data': 'parent 2', 'children': [{'data': 'child 3'}]}]
```

Personally I find it a little weird that `only`/`exclude` are arguments at the class level rather than the on `dump`, but there's some discussion of that in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/631) and also [this one](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/761).

Aside from creating separate Schema instances like this (which you were doing already and passing in context) you could potentially hack something together to modify `dump_fields` dynamically but that would seem less advisable and likely to create more problems for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - this seems like a good approach. In the end I ended up using different classes to define the different schemas.